# Error "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST" when fetching values from list

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, list

Can someone please help me here?I have the piece of code here alongwith the error I am facing.
Apex class:Code snippet:

```
Map<Id,Attachment> mapCaseAttachments = new Map<Id,attachment>();
for (List<Call2_vod__c> c : listOfLists) {
    attachment atf = mapCaseAttachments.get(c.Account_vod__C);
    attachmentCaseWrapper cw = new attachmentCaseWrapper(c,atf);
    caseWrapper.add(cw);
}
```

Error:

> Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete
>   SObject: LIST

Comment: Can you please update your question and post your `attachmentCaseWrapper`?

Comment: BTW if you're using the listOfLists example I answered your question yesterday with, you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 8):

You're cycling through a list of lists, not a list of SObjects.

```
for (List <Call_to_Vod__C> c : listOfLists) {    
  attachment atf = mapCaseAttachments.get(c.Account_vod__C);    
}
```

The error message is pretty clear actually:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST

- You have a field expression `c.Account_vod__C`
- The initial term of that expression is `c`
- `c` is not an SObject, it is a LIST

If you want to get at the SObject:

```
for (List <Call_to_Vod__C>  cs : listOfLists) {   
  for (Call_to_Vod__C c : cs)    {
     /// bla bla c.Account_vod__C   
  } 
}
```